# Eager loading using FluentNhibernate in a generic class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following model

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int EntityID { get;set; }
    public virtual bool Active { get;set; }
}

public class Brand : BaseEntity
{
   public Brand()
   {
      Series = new List<Series>();
   }

   public virtual string BrandName { get;set; }
   public virtual string Website { get;set; }
   public virtual IList<Series> Series;
}

public class Series: BaseEntity
{
   public Series()
   {
      Products = new List<Product>();
   }

   public virtual Brand Brand { get;set; }
   public virtual string SeriesName { get;set; }
   public virtual string SeriesDescription { get;set; }
   public virtual IList<Product> Products;
}

public class Product : BaseEntity
{
   public Product()
   {
      Series = new List<Series>();
   }

   public virtual Series Series { get;set; };
   public virtual string ProductName { get;set; }
   public virtual string ProductCode { get;set; }
   public virtual string ProductDescription { get;set; }
   public virtual double SellingPrice { get;set; }
}
```

I have set all mappings to not lazy load.

```
public class BrandMapping() : ClassMap<Brand>
{

    public BrandMapping()
    {
       Table("Brand");
       Id(item => item.EntityID).Column("BrandID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
       Map(item => item.BrandName).Not.LazyLoad();
       Map(item => item.Active).Not.LazyLoad();
       Map(item => item.Website).Not.LazyLoad();
       HasMany<Series>(item => item.Series).Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class SeriesMapping() : ClassMap<Series>
{

    public SeriesMapping()
    {
       Table("Series");
       Id(item => item.EntityID).Column("SeriesID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
       Map(item => item.SeriesName).Not.LazyLoad();
       Map(item => item.SeriesDescription).Not.LazyLoad();
       Map(item => item.Active).Not.LazyLoad();
       HasMany<Product>(item => item.Products).Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
       Reference<Brand>(item => item.Brand).Column("BrandID");
    }
}


public class ProductMapping() : ClassMap<Product>
{

    public ProductMapping()
    {
       Table("Product");
       Id(item => item.EntityID).Column("ProductID").GeneratedBy.Increment();
       Map(item => item.ProductName).Not.LazyLoad();
       Map(item => item.ProductDescription).Not.LazyLoad();
       Map(item => item.ProductCode).Not.LazyLoad();
       Map(item => item.SellingPrice).Not.LazyLoad();
       Map(item => item.Active).Not.LazyLoad();
       Reference<Series>(item => item.Series).Column("ProductID");
    }
}
```

I have a generic Repository base that has the following code for the Load method so I don't need to create code for each typed Repo:

```
IEnumerable<T> Load()
{
    IList<T> results = new List<T>();

    StartTransaction();
    results = _session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
    CommitTransaction();

    return results;
}
```

My issue is that one of my screens displays products. This screen needs to display the Series and Brand names for completeness in the grid. I have found that even with lazy loading disabled, the Series is not even loaded, never mind the Brand record. I need to find a way to add the SetFetchMode to the above load code to ensure that all relationship trees (Product->Series->Brand) are loaded when a record is loaded from the DB.

Anyone got ideas how I can do generic SetFetchmode?

Comment: What about your mapping classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easiest to specify eager loading in the mapping files for each entity, this is done by adding the `Fetch` specification.

If you are using Fluent nHibernate then this should do it:

```
  References(x => x.Series).Column("SeriesId").ForeignKey("Id").Fetch.Join();
```

If you put this inside your Product mapping it tells nHiberate to eager load the Series whenever a Product is loaded.

Likewise put something similar in your Series to load the Brand.